# Conditionally Fill a Column based on Another Column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe (df) where in one column I have US states by their two letter acronym; 'AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA', ..., 'WV','WY'.

I want to create a new column that reads the 'df$state' column and apply a region: West, Midwest, Northeast, Southeast, Southwest.

I have the regions broken down into lists (for example:
`list_southwest <- c('TX','AZ','NM','OK')`

I duplicated the 'df$state' column and renamed it 'df$region'. What I want to do is replace the two-letter state elements with regions and not do it state-by-state.

I have been successful with the code: `df$region [df$region == 'TX'] <- "Southwest"`

But I'd like to go faster, I tried: `df$region [df$region == 'list_west'] <- "Southwest"`

in an attempt to check the column for all the two-letter strings in "list_west" but I'm not getting anything replaced and I'm not receiving an error of any kind.

I've also tried the tedious:
`df$region [df$region == 'TX', 'AZ', ...` but r doesn't seem to like that, I've tried replacing the commas with |, &&, ||, and no luck.

I was thinking there might be a way to add a for loop and case_when(), and a lot of other things, but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I'm hoping for without having to run a line of code per each individual state:

| state | region |
| --- | --- |
| AK | West |
| AL | South |
| AR | South |
| AZ | West |
| CA | West |
| CO | West |
| CT | NorthEast |

**SOLVED!!**
Here's how the code looks after a comment to use %in% versus ==:

`df$region [df$region %in% list_west] <- "West"`

Comment: Use %in% rather than "=="

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!!

Here's the code I changed to get things working:

```df$region [df$region %in% list_west] <- "West"

Thank you so much!